# I want to run this code on oracle 10g but it gives me an error

Tags: oracle

When I run this it gives me the error

> ORA-00911: invalid character

```
CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY CDATA AS 'D:\';
    GRANT READ ON DIRECTORY CDATA TO PUBLIC;
    DECLARE
    MYFILE UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
    type array IS VARRAY(10) OF INTEGER;
    arr array;
    temp number;
    curr number;
    prev number;
    n number;
    BEGIN
    MYFILE := UTL_FILE.FOPEN('CDATA','FILING.txt','W');
       arr := array(98, 97, 78, 87, 92, 33, 12, 45, 45, 66);
       n:= arr.count;
       UTL_FILE.PUT(MYFILE, 'ORGANIZED DATA: ');
          for i in 2..arr.count loop
             curr:=i;
             prev:=i-1;
              while arr(prev) > arr(curr) loop
                       temp:= arr(curr);
                       arr(curr):= arr(prev);
                       arr(prev):= temp;
                       curr:= curr-1; 
                       prev:= prev-1;
                    IF curr=1 THEN
                     EXIT;
                    END IF;                 
              end loop;
          end loop;
       for i in 1.. arr.count loop
          UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(MYFILE, arr(i));
          dbms_output.put_line(arr(i));
       end loop;
    UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(MYFILE);
    END;     //ORA-00911: invalid character
// File is not writting
```

> Unable to write sorted data into file from insertion algorithm

Comment: What tool are you using to run these commands? sqlplus?

Comment: @YaronIdan Oracle 10g

Comment: I know, you've mentioned that in your question's subject, I was asking about the tool you are using to interact with Oracle.

Comment: How are you accessing your Oracle DB? What program do you use?

Comment: I think we're done here

Comment: Is `Unable to write sorted data into file from insertion algorithm` part of the error you get?

Comment: Are you sure you're using Internet Explorer to access the database? What web app are you using, if so? Are you sure it isn't an app like TOAD?

Comment: What do you meant by tools? IS it SQL?

Comment: ..... epic !! :D :D

Answer (score 0):

I ran your query as a normal (public) user. There was no error as ORA-00911: invalid character. There was another error, which is expected as per the code you are running. When I ran your script as a dba user, there was no error at all.

***First Approach:***    As a public user, you would get first error as

> "insufficient privileges"

when the create directory line executes. Then you would get

> "directory does not exist"

when the plsql script executes.

This is because, the directory creation and grant script have to run with dba privilege (it is a privilege that user account like 'sys' possess). The rest of the script i.e. that plsql block can run from a public user. As normal user does not have directory creation and grant privilege, hence the error.

Now, if you move directory creation to grant lines to run with a dba user, they will run fine, the above 2 errors would be gone. Then when you run the plsql block with a public user, there will be a third error

> "directory access denied"

. This is because, in your grant script you have given read access on the directory object to public, while in your plsql block you are actually writing to it. To handle that, modify grant script to -

```
GRANT READ,WRITE ON DIRECTORY CDATA TO PUBLIC;
```

***Second Approach***
You can run the whole script including the plsql block using a dba user, where your script would encounter no errors at all.

I would suggest the best approach would be to run directory creation and grant script from a dba user and then run the plsql block from a normal nondba user, with the grant script modified as above.